# JDBC MySQL character encoding: Why is useUnicode required?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I am confused about the Character Encoding of Mysql.
I configure connection.url in Hibernate like this :

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Bag</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

the entity class is :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "notification")
public class Notification {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "username", unique = true,nullable = false, length = 64)
private String username;

@Column(name = "title", nullable = false, length = 64)
private String title;

@Column(name = "message", nullable = false, length = 1000)
private String message;

@Column(name = "uri", nullable = true, length = 256)
private String uri;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getUri() {
    return uri;
}

public void setUri(String uri) {
    this.uri = uri;
}
```

}

I have create a table in mysql called 'notification':

```
notification | CREATE TABLE `notification` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `message` longtext NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `uri` longtext,
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

when I insert a Chinese String,it can't work well:

```
mysql> select * from notification;
+----+---------------------------------+--------------------+------+
| id | message          | title          | uri          |username |
+----+---------------------------------+--------------------+--------
|  1 | ??,????????      | ????           |/post/toPluto | pluto    |
```

I have solved the problem by changing connection.url to :

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Bag?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</property>
```

But I don't know the reason,could someone tell me the reason?

this is mysql character_set

```
Variable_name Value                                                                     
| character_set_client     | utf8    
|
| character_set_connection | utf8          
|
| character_set_database   | utf8     
| character_set_filesystem | binary        
|
| character_set_results    | utf8    
|
| character_set_server     | latin1    
|
| character_set_system     | utf8     
|
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/mysql-5.7.11-       

osx10.9x86_64/share/charsets/ |
```

this is the hex of Chinese String:

```
mysql> select hex(message) from notification;
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| hex(message)                                                   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 3F3F2C3F3F3F3F3F3F3F3F
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the MySQL Connector/J documentation section

[5.4 Using Character Sets and Unicode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html)

> The character encoding between client and server is automatically detected upon connection. You specify the encoding on the server using the `character_set_server` for server versions 4.1.0 and newer, and `character_set` system variable for server versions older than 4.1.0. The driver automatically uses the encoding specified by the server. For more information, see Server Character Set and Collation.
>
> [...]
>
> To override the automatically detected encoding on the client side, use the `characterEncoding` property in the URL used to connect to the server.

You need to specify `useUnicode` and `characterEncoding` properties in your connection settings to override the `character_set_server` setting of `latin1` on your server.